# Getting a segfault when I want to return string length in ARM assembler on a raspberry

Tags: string, arm

So I'm a beginner in ARM assembler. 
I'm trying to return the length of "Hello, World!", so it must be 13. Here is my source code:

```
.section .rodata

.align 2

message:

.string "Hello, world!"

afficher:

        .string "%d"

        .text
        .align 2
        .global main
long:

        stmfd   sp!, {lr}
        ldrb    r2, [r0]
        cmp     r2, #0
        beq     out
        add     r1,r1,#1
        add     r0,r0, #1
        bl      long
        ldmfd   sp!, {lr}
        bx      lr
        .global main

main:                           

        stmfd   sp!, {lr}
        ldr     r0, =message    
        mov     r1, #0
        bl      long
        ldmfd   sp!, {lr}
        bx      lr 

out :

        ldr     r6, =message 
        bl      printf
        mov     r0, r1     
        ldr     r3, =afficher
        mov     r4, r1
        mov     r5, r0
        bl      printf
        .global main
```

I don't know where is the problem honestly. Can anyone help me please?! thanx

Comment: Wowzers, I've never seen `strlen` implemented _recursively_ before... Anyway, first thing would be to run it under a debugger to find _where_ the segfault happens, and whether the address being accessed is obviously nonsense (suggesting data corruption) or close to something reasonable (suggesting some sort of overrun).

Comment: Are you sure your string is 0-terminated?

Comment: Yes it is 0-terminated. I tried to call printf in the main label but I still have a segfault

Comment: @Notlikethat what debuggers can we use to debug arm programs?

Comment: Your code is doing many things wrong; the first is trying to do strlen recursively. The second is that you're not unwinding the stack after calling "long" multiple times. And lastly, your branch to "out" leaves the stack decremented too far and then falls off a cliff instead of returning to the OS/caller.

Comment: I still can't get it working, can you code it please. I really need it

Comment: Since the title implies you're on a Raspberry Pi, then presumably you're just running this under Linux, and that boils down to "what debuggers can we use to debug Linux programs?". Most people seem to use gdb for that, although I'm sure there are others. As for doing your homework for you, OK, here's a nice optimised version that fits the stated requirements: `mov r0, #13; bx lr`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, after some further looking up into my code, here is a working code:

```
.section .rodata       
.align 2                

 message:                        
    .string "Hello, world!" 

 print:
    .string "Length is : %d\n"

.text                   
.align 2
.global main            

strlen: 
    stmfd   sp!, {lr}
    ldrb    r2, [r0]
    cmp     r2, #0
    beq     out
    add     r1, r1, #1
    add     r0, r0, #1
    bl      strlen
    ldmfd   sp!, {lr}
    bx      lr
    .global main

main:                           
    stmfd   sp!, {lr}       
    ldr     r0, =message    
    mov     r1, #0
    bl      strlen
    ldmfd   sp!, {lr}
    bx      lr
out:

    stmfd   sp!, {lr}
    ldr     r0, =print
    mov     r3,  r1  
    bl      printf
    ldmfd   sp!, {lr}
    bx      lr
```

At first, I was giving a "Hello, world!\n" string to calculate the length, for that it returned 14, but without the "\n" it return 13. 
Thanks for your help every one , and I would welcome any other remarques on this code if you still have any!

Comment: For the love of science, don't use recursion to implement `strlen`.  That's incredibly inefficient, and uses about 4x as much stack space as the size of the string.  It's also super weird to put two halves of the function on either side of `main`.  Also weird for strlen to *print* the length instead of returning it for the caller to print or use however it wants.  C `strlen` just returns a number.